# NSLog and printing of an object

Tags: objective-c

I have a class and I want to setup what is printed when I call NSLog with that class. For example,

NSLog(@"%@",nonstandardObject);

How do I setup the object so it prints out what I'd want?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Override the `-description` method.  It takes no parameters and returns an `NSString` that get's `printf`'d out.

There's another variant called `-debugDescription` (returns `NSString`, no parameters) that's used when po'ing the object from gdb.

Comment: When subclassing from classes other than NSObject, it's worth considering adding a call to `[super description]` before outputting results for the subclass's iVars.

Comment: @Abizern - only if you're planning on using the string that `super` gives you.  Is there another reason you'd want super's description?

Comment: @Dave. Exactly, let super handle it's own description, and your class can handle the output for any added iVars. As I said; it's something to consider.