# How to keep context in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios7, scope, global-variables

I have application with authorization and each user has different data to display. Also I has in app a roles - admin or teacher. So, when user login I need to detect ID of user and his role. With this two values I need work in whole app (display correct data). How can I do it? I just thought use a global variable. Is there another option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Global variables are the worst approach, because they can be set secretly to your whole application  with a simple assignment.

2 The quick & dirty approach is to have properties of your application delegate. You can reach the application delegate from everywhere using the shared instance of `NSApplication` asking it for its delegate. This has the advantage that methods are used to read and write the state and therefore is better than 1.

3 The best approach is, to pass the values to any controller that has to know it. This is, because the second approach has a dependency on the application delegate. Since this is application specific, you cannot re-use all classes that needs the information even the classes of role and ID are standard classes.

As a pay off you have a little bit more code to type. But you are a developer, not a secretary. ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583981/nslog-and-printing-of-an-object